# Can't set up built-in PHPStorm server

Tags: networking, server, permissions

I have PHPStorm 2016.1. Jetbrains have a tutorial for built-in server setup, but it's only for Windows. I tried adapting it, but no success - the browser can't connect. Here are my settings:

[image: Connection]
[image: Mappings]
[image: Run confiduration]

When I run it from phpstorm, it says:

```
/usr/bin/php7.0 -S localhost:80 -t "/home/alexiy/PHPStorm local server"
[Fri Apr 15 09:04:51 2016] Failed to listen on localhost:80 (reason: Permission denied)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: It seems you don't have permission to access `/home/alexiy/PHPStorm local server`. Have you already tried to change path to this `"/home/alexiy/PHPStorm\ local\ server"`? \ should escape space character that in terminal are not recognized.

Answer (score 9):

Nevermind. It was an easy fix - just changed the port to 8080.

Comment: for security reasons, a user (not root) is not allowed to allocate ports below 1024. So you got 'permission denied' for port 80. But port 8080 works and any port > 1024 should work (if available).